# Finding the Probability with Moment Generating Function

Tags: statistics

This is a question in a book, but I don't know how to solve it.

### Problem

if $X$ is a random variable with $M_X(t)=e^{2t+2t^2}$ then find $P\{|X -\frac{1}{2}|>2\}$.
Question didn't say anything about $X$ distribution (discrete or continuous)

#### My Solution

**Find exact value**

for solve this I first try this fact that $$ M_X(ln(t))= \psi_X(t) $$
and
$$\frac{\partial^k}{\partial t^k}\psi_X(t)|_{t=0}=k!f_X(k)$$

if I calculate $\psi_X(t)$, it is:
$$\psi_X(t)=t^2e^{2(lnt)^2}$$

but because of $t^2$ there is no easy way to calculate $\psi_X(t)$ and if I put $k=0$, I couldn't find $f_x(0)$ because of $ln(0)$!!
Besides, I can only find $f(0), f(1), ...$ but I don't think that our distribution is discrete.

**Find upper/lower**

I want to know, Is there any way to find upper/lower for probability?

We find upper/lower for $P\{|X -\frac{1}{2}|>2\}$ with Chebyshev inequality. We know that $\mu=2$ and $\sigma=2$ from $M_X(t)$ Derivations, but I couldn't convert given probability to this form:
$$P\{|X-\mu|<k\sigma\} \ge 1-\frac{1}{k^2}$$
Is it possible to show me how to convert it to above form?

Is it possible to show me something for solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: MGFs of some standard distributions have a known form. In all those cases, you can identify the distribution just by looking at the MGF. The one in your question is a known MGF, that of a Normal distribution.

Comment: wow. it is great. I don't know this. however is there any other way to solve it? because this question is related to Chebyshev and Moment Generating Function not especial distributions? (we don't have normal table in question)

Comment: @Amin When you say Chebyshev, did you mean Chebyshev inequality? In that case, are you trying to calculate the probability precisely or upper bound it? Note that you can find the first and second moments of this distribution by expanding out the MGF (hint: write the series expansion of $e^x$) and collecting the terms with $t$ and $t^2$. After that, it will be easy to apply the inequality.

Comment: Yes. I mean Chebyshev inequality?. I did this in my question, at the bottom of question. however I couln't convert given probability to Chebyshev inequality form. Is it possible to help me?

Comment: The question seems to be asking for the exact value of $P(|X -\frac{1}{2}|>2)$ so is unlikely to need the Chebyshev inequality.  But you can find the mean and variance from the Moment Generating function

Comment: Yes I know. Can you read buttom of my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help from @StubbornAtom.
The given $M_X(t)$ is generator of Normal distribution with $\mu=2$ and $\sigma^2=4$ so this given probability is:
$$P\{|X -\frac{1}{2}|>2\} = 1 - P\{|X -\frac{1}{2}| \le 2\} = 
1 - P\{-\frac{3}{2} \le X \le \frac{5}{2}\}$$

If we convert $X$ to standard normal distribution with this change:
$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{X-2}{2} $$ 
so given probability is:
$$1 - P\{-\frac{3}{2} \le X \le \frac{5}{2}\} = 1 - P\{-1.7 \le Z \le 0.25\} = 
1-(P\{Z \le0.25\} - P\{Z \le-1.7\}) = 1 - (0.5987 - 0.0446) = 1 - 0.5541 = 0.4459$$

Thanks for help.